# Can I rollback a transaction after commiting it with Datamapper/Codeigniter?

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, transactions, codeigniter-datamapper

Is it possible to rollback a transaction after it has been commited? 
I ask this because in the Datamapper documentation i see the `trans_begin()` method, but i didn't find the `trans_end()` method. Codeigniter has the `trans_complete()` method, so i assumed Datamapper might have a similar method.

One thing I found interesting is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4070306/can-i-rollback-a-sqlite-transaction-after-it-has-been-commited/4070406#4070406). Is there anything similar to a savepoint in Datamapper/Codeigniter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/pages/transactions.html
>
> DataMapper handles transactions in very much the same way that
>   CodeIgniter does (read CodeIgniter Transactions), obviously because it
>   uses the same methods! The only real difference is that you'll be
>   calling the transaction methods directly on your DataMapper objects.

This means that instead of:

```
$this->db->trans_begin();
```

You'd use:

```
$my_datamapper_object->trans_begin();
```

Everything else, according to the Datamapper documentation, is **identical to Codeigniter** in regards to transactions. If you look at the source code for the Datamapper library, you'll see that all `trans_*()` calls are simply wrapper functions. Example:

```
// Datamapper.php 1.8.dev line 3975
/**
 * Trans Complete
 *
 * Complete a transaction.
 *
 * @return  bool Success or Failure
 */
public function trans_complete()
{
    return $this->db->trans_complete();
}
```

A `trans_end()` method does not exist in either Codeigniter or Datamapper. You'd use `trans_start()` and `trans_complete()` for automatic transactions, or to call them manually:

> http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/transactions.html
>
> #### Running Transactions Manually
>
> If you would like to run transactions manually you can do so as
>   follows:
>
> ```
> $this->db->trans_begin();
>
> $this->db->query('AN SQL QUERY...');
> $this->db->query('ANOTHER QUERY...');
> $this->db->query('AND YET ANOTHER QUERY...');
>
> if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE)
> {
>     $this->db->trans_rollback();
> }
> else
> {
>     $this->db->trans_commit();
> }
> ```

Just replace `$this->db` with your Datamapper object. For example.

```
$u = new User($id);
$u->trans_begin();
$u->name = 'Jorge';
$u->save();

if ($u->trans_status() === FALSE)
{
    $u->trans_rollback();
}
else
{
    $u->trans_commit();
}
```