# How to add multiple rows in datamapper using same object

Tags: php, mysql, database, datamapper

I know that using $dataMapperObject->query('INSERT INTO table (a,b) VALUES (1,2), (2,3), (3,4);'); will save multiple records as it's simple sql INSERT statement.

But how to store multiple values in same object of datamapper?

Example:

```
$addPatient= new Patient_table();  
$addPatient->trans_begin();
foreach($_POST as $key=>$val){
    $addPatient->patient_id=$this->patient-id;
    $addPatient->question=$key;
    $addPatient->answer=$val;
    $addPatient->save();
}
```

Here in above example i want to store each and every question and answer successfully. If any of one is missing i wants to rallback entire transaction.

How to store all question answer in single object call?

Comment: What do you mean with single object call? I think i understand what you want but if i am wrong correct me. for each patient you start adding the question and answers but if one is empty you want to undo adding the previously added questions and answers for that patient?

Comment: Yes @Jester you got it.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not that familiar with using datamapper but i think the following should work:

```
$addPatient= new Patient_table();  
$addPatient->trans_begin();
foreach($_POST as $key=>$val){
    $addPatient->patient_id=$this->patient-id;
    $addPatient->question=$key;
    $addPatient->answer=$val;
    $addPatient->save();
}
if ($addPatient->trans_status() === FALSE)
{
    $addPatient->trans_rollback();
}
else
{
    $addPatient->trans_commit();
}
```

I think your database fields might have to be set so that they may not contain null, here is another post on the same topic.
[Can I rollback a transaction after commiting it with Datamapper/Codeigniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208439/can-i-rollback-a-transaction-after-commiting-it-with-datamapper-codeigniter)